# docker build --build-arg with github password is not working

Tags: docker

When my Dockerfile was like below, it was working well.

```
...
RUN pip install git+https://user_name:my_password@github.com/repo_name.git#egg=repo_name==1.0.0
...
```

But when I changed Dockerfile to the below

```
...
RUN pip install git+https://user_name:${GITHUB_PASSWORD}@github.com/repo_name.git#egg=repo_name==1.0.0
...
```

And used the command below, it's not working.

```
docker build -t my_repo:tag_name . --build-arg GITHUB_PASSWORD=my_password
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an ARG declaration into the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG PASSWORD

RUN echo ${PASSWORD} > /password
```

Then build your docker image:

```
$ docker build -t foo . --build-arg PASSWORD="foobar"
```

After this, you can check for the existence of the parameter in your docker container:

```
$ docker run -it foo bash
root@ebeb5b33941e:/# cat /password 
foobar
```

Therefore, add the ARG GITHUB_PASSWORD build arg into your dockerfile to get it to work.